# Jquery to add additional Select-boxs

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on web form that asks for AP courses taken by incoming students and i am trying to use JQuery so i they can add another course if they took more than one along with their score this will eventually go into a database i have not had any luck on getting this to work properly i need to keep the course and scores together

I was using this as an example but haven't had much luck with my data
http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/tZPg4/5132/

```
<p> Please list all of the AP tests you have taken and their scores. </p>

<label for="apCourses"> 
<select name="apCourses">
<option name="none" value="none"> does not apply </option>
<option name="one" value="one"> Art History </option>
<option name="two" value="two"> Art 2-D </option>
<option name="three" value="three"> Art- Drawing </option>
<option name="three" value="three"> Biology </option>
<option name="three" value="three"> Calculus AB </option>
<option name="three" value="three"> Calculus BC </option>
<option name="three" value="three"> Computer Science </option>
<option name="three" value="three"> Chemistry </option>
<option name="three" value="three"> English Lang &amp; Composition</option>
<option name="three" value="three"> English Literature/Comp </option>
<option name="three" value="three"> Environmental Science </option>
<option name="three" value="three"> Government/US </option>
<option name="three" value="three"> Government/Comp </option>
<option name="three" value="three"> US History </option>
<option name="three" value="three"> European History </option>
<option name="three" value="three"> World History </option>
<option name="three" value="three"> Foreign Language </option>
<option name="three" value="three"> Foreign Literature </option>
<option name="three" value="three"> Latin - Lit </option>
<option name="three" value="three"> Latin -Vergil </option>
<option name="three" value="three"> Macroeconomics </option>
<option name="three" value="three"> Microeconomics </option>
<option name="three" value="three"> Music Theory </option>
<option name="three" value="three"> Physics B </option>
<option name="three" value="three"> Physics C Mechanics </option>
<option name="three" value="three"> Physics C, Electricity and Magnetism </option>
<option name="three" value="three"> Psychology </option>
<option name="three" value="three"> Human Geography </option>
<option name="three" value="three"> three </option>
</select> </label>


<label for="apScore">Score:</label>
<select name="apScore">
<option name="0" value="0"> 0 </option>
<option name="1" value="1"> 1 </option>
<option name="2" value="2"> 2 </option>
<option name="3" value="3"> 3 </option>
<option name="4" value="4"> 4 </option>
<option name="5" value="5"> 5 </option>

</select>
```

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/satishbejgum/Sfxnx/3/

Comment: your jsfiddle seems to work. what exactly is your question ?

Comment: Here's an update of Satish's with the score select: http://jsfiddle.net/N6fXN/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your HTML example above, I've added a button element that will allow the user to add more course and then wrap the course and score select boxes in a div

```
<p> Please list all of the AP tests you have taken and their scores. </p>

<div id="select-boxes-container">
    <div>
       //your select boxes 
       <button class="button-add">Add another course</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

using jQuery:

```
$('#select-boxes-container').on('click', '.button-add', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#select-boxes-container').append($(this).closest('div').clone());
    $(this).removeClass('button-add')
    .addClass('button-remove')
    .text('Remove');
});
$('#select-boxes-container').on('click','.button-remove', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/AAmj5/

Hope that helps!

Comment: I tested this with my form , the button doesn't seem to add anymore courses it submits my form

Comment: It submits because you're not preventing the default action.

Comment: Hi there, you can prevent that by add calling the preventDefault function, will edit the code. I already updated the jsfiddle btw.

Comment: This is all super helpful thanks! i am still having the issue of the add course button submitting the form even with the preventDefault function and not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Hi There, if you can create a jsfiddle of the form that will be helpful for us to identify the problem. In the meantime, you can replace the button element with an anchor element instead, see example here: http://jsfiddle.net/joeyend/H6Jjn/1/